# Upload a document to a SharePoint list from CSOM with no limitations

Tags: client-object-model, file-upload, metadata

I need to upload a document to a SharePoint list or folder using the Client Side Object Model from .NET (C#). What is the best way to do this? The requirements are as follows:

- Set metadata values
- No limitation on file size
- Must work with libraries that exceed the List View Threshold

Answer (score 3):

```
           SPFile file = oListItem.File;

           StreamReader fsReader = new StreamReader(file.OpenBinaryStream());
           byte[] contents = null;
           using (Stream fStream = fsReader.BaseStream)
           {
               contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
               fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
               fStream.Close();
           }


           ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("SITE URL");
           Web _Site = clientContext.Web;
           List _List = _Site.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");

           FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
           newFile.Content = contents;  //bytes here
           newFile.Url = _FileName;
           newFile.Overwrite = true;

           Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File _UploadingFile =                
           _List.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

           clientContext.Load(_UploadingFile);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

           CamlQuery _CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();
           _CamlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>" + _Name + "</Value>" +
                                "</Contains></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
           ListItemCollection _ListItemCollection = _List.GetItems(_CamlQuery);
           clientContext.Load(_ListItemCollection);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

           int _count = _ListItemCollection.Count;

           ListItem _ListItem = _ListItemCollection[0];
           _ListItem["ColName1"] = ColValue1;
           _ListItem["ColName2"] = ColValue2;

           _ListItem.Update();

           clientContext.Load(_ListItem);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("share point url");//httP://xyz.com/yoursharepoint library
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fci.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Your File Physical path");//D:\ filename
                    fci.Url = "SP-UploadTest";
                    fci.Overwrite = true;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fileToUpload = folder.Files.Add(fci);
                    ctx.Load(fileToUpload);
```